# How to display overlay loading icon and while fetching an API in React native Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

Am trying to display a loading icon or text while I fetch an API and then remove it after fetching, am using typescript for react native,

below is what I have so far

```
useEffect(() => {
   const newsUrl = 'http://172.20.10.4:8000/mobile/news';
   fetch(newsUrl, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        let newArr = [...data];
        setProducts(newArr);
        // loadingText.hide()  or something similar
    })  }, []);
```

And below is the return part of the code

```
return (
<Block>
  {/* I want to display this while loading */}
  <Block color={colors.card} flex={0} padding={sizes.padding}>
    <Text>Loading News .......</Text>
  </Block>

  {/* toggle products list */}

     
     

  {/* And display this when done loading */}
  <Block
    scroll
    paddingHorizontal={sizes.padding}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: sizes.l}}>
    <Block row wrap="wrap" justify="space-between" marginTop={sizes.sm}>
      {products?.map((product) => (
        <Product {...product} key={`card-${product?.id}`} />
      ))}
    </Block>
  </Block>
</Block>
  );
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a loading state with `useState`.

Add `setLoading(true)` before you call `fetch`.

Add `setLoading(false)` at the same time you call `setProducts(newArr)`

Test for that:

```
if (loading) {
    return <LoadingNews />
}

return <ThingThatUsesProducts />
```

---

Alternatively you can use a single `products` state and test based on some condition of it (e.g. `if (products === null) { return <LoadingNews /> }`).